# How to troubleshoot overlapping java modules in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, dependencies, java-module

I've got a Spring Boot 2  / Java 11 application using Gradle. When I run it using `gradle bootRun` it works fine, but if I try to run it from within IntelliJ (using the normal "Run" action on the main class, rather than running a gradle task), it fails with this error:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
> java.lang.LayerInstantiationException: Package
> com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.keys.content.keyvalues in
> both module `xml.security.impl` and module `java.xml.crypto`

So it seems like there's something wrong with my IntelliJ setup, but I'm fairly new to IntelliJ and have no idea how to locate the source of this problem.

When investigating with gradle's `dependencyInsight`, I see a transitive dependency on `com.sun.xml.security:xml-security-impl:1.0`, but no dependencies on `java.xml.crypto`.

What can I check to track down the cause of this?

---

now seeing a similar error when using "Build and run with" = gradle:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
> java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Module java.activation contains
> package javax.activation, module jakarta.activation exports package
> javax.activation to java.activation

works fine using `gradlew bootRun`, so it seems to be specific to something in IntelliJ, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: tried excluding the transitive dependency, confirmed with `dependencyInsight`, but IntelliJ still sees both of them. Why would it be seeing dependencies not declared in Gradle?

Comment: Try using `jdeps` to analyze the dependencies. What version of IntelliJ are you using? On executing the main class, IntelliJ prints the complete java command that has been resolved to make it run in its own Run window.

Comment: `but IntelliJ still sees both of them` how do you know this? Also what Gradle `dependencies` task show for them? Do you use Java 9 modules and `module-info`?Can you attach a minimal sample project? This way it will be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: What do you have for Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Build and run using** option?

Comment: @Andrey I know it sees them because I still get the error about the package appearing in both modules. I grepped the output of `gradlew dependencies --configuration runtimeClasspath` and didn't find either of them. I'm using Java 11 with modules. "Build and run using: " = IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: It does seem to work with "Build and run using: " = Gradle . I'm just hitting a limitation of IntelliJ's internal handling of gradle projects then?

Comment: Use Navigate | Class action to find jars from both dependencies and see where do they come from. You also see the dependencies which are used by application in module's [dependencies tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/modules.html). It would be nice to check this in a sample project.

Comment: „*…so it seems to be specific to something in IntelliJ…*“ — Yet you don't think it would be of any value to share more *specific* details about IntelliJ? — „*Why would it be seeing dependencies not declared in Gradle?*“ — I have a hunch. But it would be premature for anybody to speculate before you share more specifics about your IDE and your dependencies. — „*a limitation of IntelliJ's internal handling of gradle projects then?*“ — Could be. It could be something else entirely. I see from your avatar you're a Perl man. Like Wall says: *Tim Toady*. Could it also be operator error? Who can say?